# Async task does not call OnPostExecute or onProgressUpdate after I manually force quit the app and relaunch

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask` that downloads files in `doInBackground()` method. I am testing my app before releasing it. When I manually force quit the app and relaunch it, the `doInBackground()` seems to be invoked, but not `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()`. My `onPostExecute()` call methods that cause UI changes.

How can I make sure the `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate()` get called? I also see the following warning:

`Activity` stop timeout for `ActivityRecord` or `Activity` destroy timeout for `ActivityRecord` or `Activity` idle timeout for `ActivityRecord`

Code:

```
public void OnCreate(){

    new RefreshMyDashboardTask().execute();
}

private class RefreshMyDashboardTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(params);
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) { 
        // my server calls are called here.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably explain the flow of WHY the async task is getting invoked.

Comment: @user1408774 : Don't just describe what is happening - post code.

Comment: added code sample. My concern is why does postexecute or progress update not get invoked if I force quit and relaunch?

Comment: I am also referencing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886280/async-task-does-not-call-onpostexecute-or-onprogressupdate-after-i-manually-forc

Comment: Does `onCancelled()` get called?

Comment: Nope, I added a log.v in onCancelled() which never got displayed.

Comment: You might consider explaining **completely and precisely** what you mean by "force quit".

Comment: I go to Setting and click on the app and click on "Force Close". Then I relaunch the app to test it. I am doing this test to catch any issues users may have if app force quits in between.

Comment: "I am doing this test to catch any issues users may have if app force quits in between." -- what makes you think that this is a valid test of anything, other than what happens when the user clicks on "Force Stop"?

Comment: Ok, if user clicks on Force Close for some reason, I would like to be able to resume the async onPostExecute Task. I am wondering why would doInBackground is invoked but not onPostExecute()?

Comment: In my doInBackground() method of async task, I was writing into a file in append mode. This was causing a issue to block it from invoking onPostExecute(). I stopped writing into the file in append mode (since it was not required for me write in append mode anyway!) This solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you kill your app, or if the system kills it, then AsyncTask threads for your app get killed. They're all part of your app's process; threads can't survive outside the process that started them.

Even an IntentService might not survive a force quit. That's why task killers are such a bad idea.

In short, what you're seeing is expected behavior.

Comment: But this happens after my force quit of the app for second time. When I force quit it first time & relaunch, the app displays UI as if Async task has invoked OnPostExecute.

Comment: @user1408774: "When I force quit it first time & relaunch, the app displays UI as if Async task has invoked OnPostExecute" -- you are misinterpreting your results, somehow. "Force Stop" terminates your process, period.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare. When I launch the app after my second time force close, my UI is black and my logs show that doInBackground is executing. How is that possible? I would expect everything to stop.